# Is there a way to send ISPF commands and get job statistics using python script on Mainframe?

Tags: python, mainframe, ispf

I'm trying to automate some manual tasks on Mainframe using python script and to do that I need job status.. I know there is FTP library to login mainframe but I'm not able to send commands and get job statistics.. please suggest if there is any documentation..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What statistics are you looking to get?

Comment: Can you use JES2's FTP support?

Comment: Also, you probably already have an automation package; you might see if that can do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you're after concerning "job statistics", but there are a set of APIs provided by z/OSMF that can be invoked from any REST requester. A jobs interface is included. Docs on these APIs are found here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.izua700/IZUHPINFO_RESTServices.htm

z/OSMF must be installed on your z/OS system before using this; it's not always there. Your systems programmer should know whether it's up, running and usable and whether you would have authority to use those services.